# How to access Bitrise Secret Environment Variable in Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, environment-variables, bitrise

I'm using Bitrise as a CI solution for my iOS app. I would like not to commit my API token to the repository, hence I've stored it as a Secret in the workflow in Bitrise with key = **"API_TOKEN"**

I need to pass that value to my app as an environment variable and use it as follows:

```
ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["API_TOKEN"]
```

However, this is always nil.

My bitrise.yml contains the following:

```
....
app:
  envs:
    - API_TOKEN: "${API_TOKEN}"
...
```

How can I correctly set the Secret from Bitrise as an environment variable for my iOS app?

Comment: In theory this should work  Can it be that you did not mark the Secret to be available for Pull Requests and the builds you checked are PR builds? If that's not the problem, can you post your bitrise.yml or a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @ViktorBenei unfortunately it was not that. Meanwhile I've learned that you can't pass env variables to the iOS app via bitrise.yml.
What I've ended up doing was creating a yml file with the API_TOKEN from Bitrise secrets and get the token from file inside my app.

Comment: Ahh, for some reason I thought you're writing a bitrise step in Swift and you wanted to pass the secret to that :D Indeed if you want to make a secret available in your app you have to compile it into the app in some way. Writing it into a file like you mentioned should work :)